# open_model_zoo demos stuck at reading model

Tags: python, bert-language-model, openvino

I execute some open_model_zoo demos, it works successfully when I choose the CPU device.
But when I change the device to MYRIAD or GPU, it will stuck and do nothing.
(I've used hello_query_device.py to checked, my PC can detected the neural compute stick 2 )

Version : openvino_2022.1.0.643 at Windows10

[picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BXvM.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-squad-0001 model is supported on CPU and GPU, while wav2vec2-base model is supported on CPU only.

Refer to [Intel’s Pre-Trained Models Device Support](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_models_intel_device_support.html#) and P[ublic Pre-Trained Models Device Support](https://docs.openvino.ai/2022.1/omz_models_public_device_support.html) for Open Model Zoo models' compatibility with CPU, GPU and MYRIAD devices.